# UIWebView doesn't load content

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I don't understand why if I load the content of a `UIWebView` in XCode this way:

```
NSString *string = @"http://www.dummyurl.org/dummy.pdf";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[my_view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

everything works fine, but if a build the original string from a php script I wrote:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"www.myserver.php"];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[my_view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

nothing works. I checked my script and it returns EXACTLY the original string (http://www.dummyurl.org/dummy.pdf) that works fine with the first method.

I build from a PHP script the content of a `UITextView` too, but that works fine.
I don't understand why this method works with the `UITextView` but not with the `UIWebView` to load the .pdf.

Comment: try NSLog(@"%@", strURL); and tell us what you get from the php file. because sometimes there are spaces etc that might cause this. also you need to add this line before sending the request :  `NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];` and then use requestObj to submit the loadRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be useful

```
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSString *tempString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterSet];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[my_view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: This actually worked. I didn't even considered to use a CharacterSet, I thought a NSString was enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you linked the webview (IBOutlet) and the delegate.

With this lines it should load a url:

```
webView.delegate = self;
NSURLRequest *urlRequest;
NSString *urlToOpen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToOpen]];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I had this and it was a cache problem:

```
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
```